# Subfloat spacing issue: Why the difference?

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption, mdframed, horizontal-spacing

I'm having a spacing issue with a figure environment inside a framed box.  The figure has two subfloats on each row, like what the MWE below is showing:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup{figurename=Figure,margin=1in,format=hang,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={up}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0cm,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={up},textfont={up}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
    frametitle={This one box isn't right!},
    frametitlealignment=\centering,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily,
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!20,
    linecolor=black,
    backgroundcolor=white,
    linewidth=0.5pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    topline=true,
    bottomline=true,
    innertopmargin=1ex,
    shadow=true,
    shadowsize=1.5pt,
    shadowcolor=gray!30
]

\smallskip

Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Une balle lancée verticalement vers le haut.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-a}}
        \\
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-b}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Un bloc glissant vers le bas d'un plan incliné.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-c}}
        \\
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-a}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-b}}
        \\
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-c}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image}}
        %\caption{description}
    \end{figure}

\end{mdframed}

% Why the next similar code works?  Notice the different code formatting:

\newpage
\begin{mdframed}[
    frametitle={This one box has the proper look, but why the first one doesn't?},
    frametitlealignment=\centering,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily,
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!20,
    linecolor=black,
    backgroundcolor=white,
    linewidth=0.5pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    topline=true,
    bottomline=true,
    innertopmargin=1ex,
    shadow=true,
    shadowsize=1.5pt,
    shadowcolor=gray!30
]

\smallskip

Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  Blablabla blabla bla.  

    % DEUX FIGURES ALIGNÉES :
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Une balle lancée verticalement vers le haut.]{
            \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image}
            }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{
            \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-a}
            }
        \\
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{
            \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-b}
            }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Un bloc glissant vers le bas d'un plan incliné.]{
            \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-c}
            }
        \\
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{
            \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-a}
            }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{
            \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-b}
            }
        \\
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{
            \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image-c}
            }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[A short one line description.]{
            \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4.25cm]{example-image}
            }
        %\caption{description}
    \end{figure}

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

The first framed box has the spacing issue with the subloat descriptions (some are just a bit larger than their picture).  The second framed box has no apparent issue, but then it's the same code as the first box, but the code formatting isn't the same.  Why is there a difference in the output?  How can we fix the first box code?